# SOAP client with Zend framework 2

Tags: php, soap, zend-framework2, soap-client

I'm trying to create a SOAP client in Zend framework 2, I've created the below which returns the data correctly

```
try {
  $client = new Zend\Soap\Client("http://www.webservicex.net/country.asmx?WSDL");
  $result = $client->GetCountries();      
  print_r($result);
} catch (SoapFault $s) {
  die('ERROR: [' . $s->faultcode . '] ' . $s->faultstring);
} catch (Exception $e) {
  die('ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage());
}
```

however when I try to send data to the webservice for example using

```
try {
  $client = new Zend\Soap\Client("http://www.webservicex.net/country.asmx?WSDL");
  $result = $client->GetCurrencyByCountry('Australia');
  print_r($result);
} catch (SoapFault $s) {
  die('ERROR: [' . $s->faultcode . '] ' . $s->faultstring);
} catch (Exception $e) {
  die('ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage());
}
```

I just get the following message

```
ERROR: [soap:Receiver] System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Procedure or function 'GetCurrencyByCountry' expects parameter '@name', which was not supplied. at WebServicex.country.GetCurrencyByCountry(String CountryName) --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

How do I supply parameters to the webservices ?

Comment: Can you provide a sample XML of the request?

Comment: Not sure how I can output the raw XML

Comment: Immediately after the call to handle() you can call the getLastRequest() and getLastResponse() methods. This you could write to a file.

Comment: print_r($client->getLastRequest()); returns nothing and print_r($client->getLastResponse());returns the same soap:receiver msg

Comment: I don't control the server side, I'm connecting to a third party

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23462/discussion-between-ljt-and-axel-michel)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is in the request, the WDSL defines complex types:

```
<s:element name="GetCurrencyByCountryResponse">
    <s:complexType>
        <s:sequence>
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="GetCurrencyByCountryResult" type="s:string"/>
        </s:sequence>
    </s:complexType>
</s:element>
```

So what you need is to built an object or an assoziative array in order to be consumed by the webservice. For the object variant you can use a stdClass. If you to modify the function call like this:

```
$params = new \stdClass(); 
$params->CountryName = 'Australia'; 
$result = $client->GetCurrencyByCountry($params);
```

Your request fits the type and the data will be send to the server. In the provided WDSL there are even more complex variants you have to handle:

```
<wsdl:message name="GetISOCountryCodeByCountyNameSoapOut"> 
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetISOCountryCodeByCountyNameResponse"/> 
</wsdl:message>
```

Would need a setup like this:

```
$params = new \stdClass();
$params->parameters = new \stdClass();
$params->parameters->GetISOCountryCodeByCountyNameResult = 'YOURVALUE';
```

Or as an array:

```
$params = array('parameters'=> 
  array('GetISOCountryCodeByCountyNameResult'=>'VALUE')
);
```

Comment: For me, this setup worked for method "GetISOCountryCodeByCountyName":
**$params = array('CountryName'=> 'Australia'); $result = $client->GetISOCountryCodeByCountyName($params);**